# Apply Regular expression to SAX stream

Tags: java, xml, regex, sax

Does anybody know of a good *streaming* regular expression parser for Java?

In particular, I want to be able to watch the content of an XML element stream by and detect if and where the content matches a given regular expression.  For example, I want to watch the SAX "characters" callbacks from  the content of a MediaWiki  element stream by, but detect when where substrings matching ==([^=\n]+)== occur.

The trick is that the content comes in chunks of indeterminate size, which means that matching substrings can possibly be broken across multiple callbacks.

The simple solution is, of course, to simply buffer all the callbacks and run Java's built-in regexp engine on the long string. Unfortunately, that takes up too much memory.

The next step up in complexity is to turn the regexp into a DFA and detect when the DFA enters an "accept" state.  I was wondering if anybody know if some Java libraries to simplify this process.

I have been looking at Ragel; but that requires that the DFA be specified at compile time.

Comment: Such matching substring (as in your example) would only span a single line, what's the problem of buffering the last line (or a couple of them)?

Comment: I can't rely on the lines being of reasonable length.  Some data sets have been vandalized with long lines of garbage. Vandalism detection shouldn't be terribly hard, but I thought I'd spend a few minutes looking into this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [hitEnd](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#hitEnd%28%29) of `Matcher` might be useful in this case:

> When this method returns true, then it is possible that more input would have changed the result of the last search.

You could try to match each chunk, and if there is no match but `hitEnd` returns true you would have to append the next chunk and try again.

It would be great if the matcher somehow also returned the possible starting index, but this does not seem to be possible.

Answer (score -1):

buffer those callbacks, check for the regexp every time a tag is closed, discard the buffer

Comment: Some tags contain hundreds of megabytes of data.